# How to change theme DrawThemeTextEx font color?

Tags: delphi, winapi, themes, uxtheme

i am using [DrawThemeTextEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to draw text. i am trying to draw it in a particular color using the `crText` COLORREF member of `DTTOPS` structure:

```
procedure DrawThemeText(dc: HDC; text: WideString; font: TFont; pt: TPoint; foreColor: COLORREF);
var
   R: TRect;
   dttOpts: TDttOpts;
   hOldFont: HFONT;
   oldColor: COLORREF;
begin
   foreColor := $FF00FF00; //bright lime green
   font.

   R := Rect(pt.x, pt.y, $7fffffff, $7fffffff);

   ZeroMemory(@dttOpts, SizeOf(TDTTOpts));
   dttOpts.dwSize := SizeOf(TDTTOpts);
   dttOpts.iGlowSize := 1;
   dttOpts.crText := foreColor;
   dttOpts.dwFlags := DTT_GLOWSIZE or DTT_TEXTCOLOR;

   hOldFont := SelectObject(dc, font.Handle);
   oldColor := SetTextColor(dc, foreColor);
   try
      hr := DrawThemeTextEx(ThemeServices.Theme[teWindow], DC, WP_CAPTION, CS_ACTIVE, 
            PWideChar(Text), Length(Text),
            DT_LEFT or DT_TOP or DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOPREFIX, R, dttOpts);
   finally
      SetTextColor(dc, oldColor);
      SelectObject(dc, hOldFont);
   end;
```

Unfortunately the text color always comes out black, rather than the bright lime green color my code is specifying:

[image]

i *can* alter the **font** that is used by [selecting the new font into the device context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), i.e.:

```
   SelectObject(dc, font.Handle);
```

but neither [`SetTextColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), nor setting the `crText` and `DTT_TEXTCOLOR` options of the [`DTTOPS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, alter the text color used.

What's confusing is that the [DTTOPS structure allows me to specify a color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ```
> typedef struct _DTTOPTS
> {
>     DWORD             dwSize;              // size of the struct
>     DWORD             dwFlags;             // which options have been specified
>     COLORREF          crText;              // color to use for text fill
>     COLORREF          crBorder;            // color to use for text outline
>     COLORREF          crShadow;            // color to use for text shadow
>     ...
> ```

along with the DTT_TEXTCOLOR flag to indicate i'm using that member:

> ```
>    #define DTT_TEXTCOLOR       (1UL << 0)      // crText has been specified
> ```

What i want to accomplish *is* documented, but it's not working right. Obviously i'm doing something wrong.

How do i specify the **text color** when drawing text using [DrawThemeTextEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Are you drawing on glass or on a regular non-glass control canvas?

Comment: In this example i am drawing on regular (non-glass) canvas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `crText` member is a `ColorRef`. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449.aspx) the high-order byte "must be zero."